# Using auto and eauto to rewrite everywhere, including context, in Coq

Tags: coq

Suppose I have an equality, say `app_assoc`, that I want `auto` and `eauto` to rewrite whenever its left hand side appeared anywhere, including the context. This means that the rewriting has to be performed regardless of what the goal looks like. Is this possible?

I thought the wildcard operator `_` would stand for 'any goal' in pattern matching, so I tried

```
Hint Extern 1 ( _ ) => rewrite app_assoc in *.
```

But I get the error message `Error: Bound head variable.` Is there any way around this?

Comment: Possibly you're just trying to do too much with `auto` and should look into `Ltac` instead.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with it, but if you want some automatic rewriting, you should have a look at the ``autoewrite`` framework's documentation.

Comment: I've submitted a pull request to improve the error message: https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/1046

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad error message, and I've reported [a bug about it](https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=5723).  Coq is informing you that it's an error to begin your pattern with an `_` (though I guess the error message was written with only the variable case in mind---I don't even know what `Hint Extern 1 (fun k => k) => exfalso.` would signal, though, since you can't have a lambda as a goal).  The correct solution is

```
Hint Extern 1 => rewrite app_assoc in *.
```